# Какой методы есть в Java для использования транзакаций в БД?

Tags: java, sqlite

Пытаюсь использовать транзакации с помощью методов

```
SQLiteDataSource database;
database.beginTransaction();
database.setTransactionSuccessful();
database.endTransaction();
```

Среда разработки выдаёт ошибку на методы, возможно нужно подключить ещё какую-нибудь библиотеку ? Если да, подскажите пожалуйста какую
Если нет, то в чём ошибка?

Comment: У [SQLiteDataSource](https://static.javadoc.io/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.23.1/org/sqlite/SQLiteDataSource.html) нет таких методов. Такие методы есть в [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase) из Android API. Вы пишете программу для Android?

Comment: В том и дело, что нет. Программа формирует БД, но скорость записи очень маленькая, пытаюсь её увеличить. Как я поняла, один из способов - транзакции, но как это реализовать в программе не для Android - не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:track.db");
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
...
try {
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    connection.commit();
}
catch (SQLException exc) {
    connection.rollback();
}
```

**UPDATE:** Попробуйте добавить до начала вставки данных

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
statement.executeUpdate("PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY");
statement.executeUpdate("PRAGMA cache_size = 100000");
```

С `cache_size` надо поэкспериментировать, как и с количеством строк вставляемым в одной транзакции. Если и этим параметры не ускорят процесс, то вы достигли предела.

Comment: Вечером попробую и отпишусь, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только скорость запросов не увеличилась, не подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы `commit()` вызываете после каждого `executeUpdate()` или один после всех?

Comment: У меня не executeUpdate(), а setDouble()

Comment: Запросы делятся на фрагменты ( около 100000 строк) делаю commit() после фрагмента

Comment: Дополнил ответ.